# Running python script from php

Tags: php, python, web, cgi

I am trying to run a python script from php.

```
exec("../cgi-bin/form.py", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

I'm certain the path is correct, and that form.py is executable.

this is form.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "IN form.py'
```

However, this prints out NULL. I don't think the script is being executed. How do I make sure it is?

Comment: If you type **which python** from the command line, it should give you the full path to the python executable. You can then use that path and enter it at the top of your form.py script.

Comment: i don't have shell access :(.

Comment: You can use php exec to run the command, I suspect the return value will be **/usr/bin/python**.

Comment: @patyx7 echo exec("which python"); returns nothing.

Comment: How about exec("/usr/bin/which python", $output); ?

Comment: yep. $output is null. it's as if it's ignoring the entire line or something.

Are there any alternatives that might work?

Answer (score 4):

You're literally just typing in the location of the file. You need to tell exec to execute python with that script.

```
exec("python ../cgi-bin/form.py", $output);
```

Comment: If he specifies the correct path to python within his script and has made sure his script is executable, then it shouldn't be necessary to add python to the exec command :)

Comment: Very true, but it's fair to assume it's not executable since he wasn't getting output to begin with.

Comment: @MarcusRecck so i added headers to the form.py and i added this link to the php: echo('<a href="../cgi-bin/form.py">CLICK</a>'); which works! so directory is correct and the script runs fine. also, adding python did not do anything. still outputting null

Comment: I understand this is old, but, for Windows and possibly other machines, make sure python is located on your path.