# Calling Python file from within PHP

Tags: php, python, windows, exec

I would like to call a Python file from within PHP.
I've tried this :

```
exec('C:\Python34\python.exe ./python/genereBonDeCommande.py');
```

But it doesn't work.
In my Python file I've got this :

```
fichier = open(repertoire+"C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb/projects/Administration/bonsDeCommandes" + nom_fichier, "No13");
fichier.write('hello');
```

Then how can I call a Python file from within PHP?

Comment: Below link may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php

Comment: How to check if it did call the file ? @deepu

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running python script from php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937487/running-python-script-from-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, to create a file there is to put this line :

```
fichier = open("C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb/projects/Administration/bonsDeCommandes/No15.txt","w");
```

w creates a file if it doesn't exist already and write over if it does exist

instead of this one :

```
fichier = open(repertoire+"C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb/projects/Administration/bonsDeCommandes" + nom_fichier, "No13");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your script with the full path to your file like this:

```
<php
//If your file is in C:\wamp\www\python
exec('C:\Python34\python.exe C:\wamp\www\python\genereBonDeCommande.py');
```

Comment: It tells me "io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable" when i execute the file with the cmd

Comment: can you just echoes a value in your genereBonDeCommande.py to test where is the problem? Because maybe the error is in this file

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't want to write into the file. If i put fichier.read() instead it works properly.

Comment: @guillaumedrillaud then your question *"Then how can I call a Python file from within PHP?"* is solved the problem is other

Comment: I don't know if it works because if i put fichier.read() there is no error but i don't know if the call worked or not. How can I check if the call worked ?

Comment: @guillaumedrillaud just put in your file *print("Hello World")* and *echo exec('C:\Python34\python.exe C:\wamp\www\python\genereBonDeCommande.py');* and see the result